# What do non-chord tones do in a melody?

Tags: nonchord-tones

In the book that I am reading, I came across this passage (picture below).
But the author just tells the reader to 'consider the difference', and passes on to the next subject without explaining much.

So what do non-chord tones do exactly here?
Like unstable tones, do they drive the listener farther away from a home feeling, providing a momentum?

[image]

Comment: If the book doesn't explain, your best course of action may be to choose a different book.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what is the book, is it a theory book or practical tutorial and is it focused on classical music or not really

Comment: Why is there a vote to close? This is a good question.

Comment: There’s a whole different way to view this. A melody can be its own justification where every note is equal. When a harmony is added, the harmony doesn’t have to change with every melody note. That means some melody notes are heard over harmonies that are not closely suited to those melody notes. The point being that in cases where the melody comes first, “non-chord” tones have the exact same purpose as all other melody notes: to create a compelling melody. The fact that the harmony isn’t changing with each melody note is a harmonic, not melodic, decision.

Comment: If you harmonize the E note with a C chord, does the E become a chord tone? How about Fmaj7?

Comment: Incidentally, Randy Newman keeps it even simpler: https://youtu.be/aJbmVCgpJGA

Comment: @Peter_Mortensen If you’re using a tool to edit posts then you need to review these results manually. Your edit has made several improvements, but it’s also made a couple of bad changes.

Comment: I think it's the _implication_ behind the question that needs discussing — that non-chord tones need some sort of justification, that they're somehow less valid or less desirable than chord tones.  (And therefore, as Todd Wilcox mentions, that the melody is subservient to the harmony.)  All of which are disputable!

Comment: @Peter_Mortensen in particular, it is generally incorrect to separate a restrictive relative clause from the noun phrase it restricts.  Many other languages require commas for that purpose, but English abandoned them (I learned just yesterday) a few hundred years ago.

Comment: @phoog I'll go ahead and disagree. If I'm reading something that's nominally trying to teach about an art form such as music, I would greatly prefer it to encourage me to *consume examples of the artwork* (in this case, *listen*) so that I can appreciate subjective qualities (whether or not I can express them in language), rather than being told the author's impression of everything. Theory can only go so far. No matter how much you know about acoustics, it doesn't tell you what the sound *is*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it seems to me that the author here is telling us of his impression that non-chord tones create interest.  Maybe he could make that point with more examples, but the excerpt we've been given is singularly unsatisfying.  Examples by themselves also can only go so far.

Comment: Hm, fair enough.

Comment: IDK about tones, but when you double the number of notes, it either sounds like it should, or you get asked to stop overplaying it. I can syncopate the notes given, or *go nuts*. Usually the request is, *just play it straight*. The difference is one of those is fun to play, and the other is fun to listen to. Reminds me of the measure that I'll pick to overplay just so everyone knows I could be doing that the whole time, but they're making me go *boom-pop* over and over again. The trick is getting into a grove for it to seem like *silence* is playing those notes when you're not.

Answer (score 9):

I'll give a short, easy answer that fits into the spirit of the quote, and a longer one that challenges it.

The easy answer is that non-chord tones *either* "smooth things out," connecting melody notes to "fill in" intervallic gaps, OR "jazz things up," providing "interesting" dissonances which resolve into consonances. The book's example is in the latter category. The B in the first measure is not a member of a C chord, and clashes with any C pitch that's being played. But since the next note is a C, the dissonance resolves. We feel the dissonance all the more strongly since it was placed on a beat. The book is suggesting that a brief dose of aesthetic "unpleasantness" makes things more engaging or fun, as a bit of lemon juice or cayenne make food more interesting even though they mildly irritate our tissues.

For "smoothing things out," consider that without non-chord tones, we can only play arpeggios. A passage from Bach's C major solo violin sonata, with its implied chords, goes like this:

[image]

If we removed all non-chord tones—everything from the C measure that isn't either a C, E, or G, and everything from the G7 measure that isn't a G, B, D, or F, we'd be left with this:

[image]

This arpeggiated version feels "bumpy," instead of the fluid, "flowing" "smoothness" of the scalar version. Nothing wrong with this per se, though; sticking to arpeggiation of chordal tones works just fine for this other famous opening, working with the same "I V7," though in a different key:

[image]

---

Now, the longer version: In fairness, the book isn't trying to do a deep dive or make a very strong point. But it makes it seem as if tonality languished in chordal boredom until finally somebody invented non-chord tones, and that's not the historical case. We might *appreciate* non-chord tones by imagining life without them, but we had scalar movement in monophonic chant, long before we had any "chords" for any of the notes to be outside of. They're just a concept that evolved along *with* polyphony. Also, in the compositional process, not all non-chord tones are "garnishes," added in as afterthoughts to enliven dull melodies. This notion is more apt for some than others. I doubt that Bach started with the "bumpy," arpeggiated version, and thought "I'd like it smoother" and then filled in the gaps with passing tones. *But* some non-chord tones, like appoggiaturas, are regularly used as ornaments that the composer (or the performer!) can consciously add to a melody, to "make it more interesting," like maybe as it repeats for a second time.

Comment: There's still an A note lurking in the 2nd example! But the F notes in  the G7 bar are fine. ( Not reflected in the text above).

Comment: @Tim Thanks, good catch

Comment: My pleasure - upvoted, too!

Comment: +1 for this answer, especially the "longer version" (which is quite a bit shorter than the "short answer"....)

Comment: "Nothing wrong with this per se": indeed, but it's an entirely different experience.  So the trivial answer is that non-chord tones can turn one melody into a different (though perhaps similar) melody.  This still leaves room for an analysis of how and why.  @Tim wouldn't a jazz musician call it a G9 chord anyway on account of the A?  I think the most important point here, though, is in the second section: melody precedes harmony historically and in many compositional practices.  The idea that you start with a chord progression and fit a melody to it became prominent maybe 60 or 70 years ago.

Comment: @phoog - if you refer to the G7  chord - G13 would be an even more apposite chord!

Comment: I'm being picky here, but, "without non-chord tones we can only play arpeggios" if the melody is moving fast than the harmonic rhythm. If the two are going at the same pace, like in many hymns, or SATB styles, the lines can move by scale steps and leaps to all chord tones.

Answer (score 7):

In this particular example both non-chord tones are leading notes that strongly push for resolution on the chord tone, so they provide a bit of tension before the resolution. The second note so E into F can be also interpreted as retardation as it is approached by the same note, happens on the strong beat and a chord change and resolves half step up.

There is this nice and logical classification of non chord notes scenarios based on how the note is approached and left.

[image]

*Source: https://musictheory.pugetsound.edu/mt21c/NonChordTonesIntroduction.html*

The first non chord note from the example is interesting though as it doesn't fall easily into any of these categories even though it is not anything unusual. Appoggiatura could be the closest but that might be controversial as there seem to be different contextual definitions of appoggiatura.

Answer (score 3):

One other use of non chord tones has (fairly recently) come to be known as the "melodic-harmonic-divorce".

A good analysis can be found in this 2007 paper by David Temperley:

[*The melodic-harmonic ‘divorce’
in rock*](http://davidtemperley.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/temperley-pm07.pdf) (from the author's website)

A key point from the abstract of the article:

> A good indicator of melodic-harmonic divorce is
> cases where non-chord-tones in the melody do not resolve by step.

It tends to occur in blues, rock, and other blues-influenced music, and most often with a pentatonic melody.  It also tends to be used to contrast different passages (e.g. verse against chorus).

Comment: I saw "melodic harmonic divorce" and I immediately thought of James Taylor and Carly Simon.

Answer (score 2):

They're passing notes. I like to see them as 'stepping stones', there to get from one probably more important note to another, filling the gap, if you like. Almost an embellishment, but not really. Adding an extra bit of colour, even though the passing notes may be diatonic (chromatic notes are the real colourful ones).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, non-chord tones provide unstable dissonance to a melody which through movement to consonant chord tones provides forward momentum to music. Also, there is a general harmonic aesthetic which considers all chord tone music bland consonance and good harmony should provide a balance of consonance and dissonance. That idea is often explained with an analogy to spice in cooking. Non-chord tones would contribute to that as well. Those are two conceptions of dissonance, momentum and spice, which aren't exactly the same thing.

But there is something else very fundamental in music which has not already been addressed in other answers. Non-chord tones contribute to the *rhythm* of a line. Consider the second example, ex. 15.19b, if it were given with all chord tones...

[image]

If that line were performed without good performance articulation, it could have an effect like this...

[image]

One way to mitigate against that and get each tone clearly articulated could be with explicit breaks between repeated notes...

[image]

But another way to clearly articulate the different notes it to contrast them by pitch...

[image]

...which is one of the things the non-chord tones do in the example.

Another way to make the point about non-chord tones and their importance to rhythm is by comparing ex. 15.19a and 15.19b. The first one is almost all on the beat rhythms, but the second places the non-chord tones in accented, on the beat positions, which displaces the chord tones off the beat, and that creates the rhythmic effect of *syncopation* in the second example. The two lines are very similar in terms of pitch contour, but very different in terms of rhythm. I think you could make an strong case that the rhythmic change is much greater than the added dissonance.

Rhythm is very important in making a unique melody so the important rhythmic contribution non-chord tones make to a melody should not be overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of non chord tones is explaned by their function as ornamentation and embellishment of the melody.

Comment: Hm, this seems little more than the book's "Just look and see what they do" approach. I think the OP was looking for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Non-chord notes make the melody interesting. It gives it color, that is why it is called Chromaticisms, Chroma means color. It is like the painter with his palette of paint colors, the non-chordal notes are all ways in which the composer gives color to his/her music or in other words how it is made interesting. The moment you use non-chordal notes in a chord progression the passage starts to sound like music.

Comment: Non-chord tones are not necessarily chromatic, as seen in the example given by the OP.